# Erro PHP Built in Server Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Tags: php, windows

Eventualmente no console ou cmd aparece o erro `Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)`, note que entendo o que EOF significa, que é ***E***nd **O**f **F**ile, mas não entendo porque exatamente isto ocorre.

No inicio pensei ser algo relacionado a conflitos com IPV6, mas não estou certo disto agora, note que estou usando um script de roteamento, o resultado é algo como:

> ```
> PHP 5.6.14 Development Server started at Tue Oct 04 10:39:40 2016
> Listening on http://localhost:9000
> Document root is C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\GitHub\inphinit
> Press Ctrl-C to quit.
> [Tue Oct 04 10:40:13 2016] ::1:62748 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
> [Tue Oct 04 10:40:13 2016] ::1:62749 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
> ```

Note que o servidor não para de funcionar, estou apenas curioso para entender o porque disto

O comando esta assim:

```
php -S localhost:9000 router.php
```

Ele está assim basicamente:

```
<?php

$serverPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../');
$serverPath = rtrim(strtr($serverPath, '\\', '/'), '/') . '/';

$path = urldecode(preg_replace('#\?(.*)$#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$path = ltrim($path, '/');

if (
    $path !== '' &&
    $path !== '/' &&
    strcasecmp($path, 'system') !== 0 &&
    stripos($path, 'system/') !== 0 &&
    file_exists($serverPath . $path)
) {
    return false;
}

echo 'Oi';
```

O problema parece só ocorrer quando uso um script de roteamento, notei o problema em windows, mas não cheguei a testar em ambientes unix-like e não sei se isto ocorre neles, fiz os testes em:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- PHP 5.6.14 x64 e x86

Testei em duas máquinas diferentes

Comment: Aparentemente é um [*bug*](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60471).  Já tentou limpar o cache do navegador? ou tentar em "modo privado"?

Comment: @stderr vou tentar e vou até tentar um browser diferente do chrome ae lhe aviso :)

Comment: msm usando versoes do windows em 64 bits, suas instalacoes tanto de php quando apache devem ser 32 bits para evitar dores de cabeca.

Comment: @TiagoNET não é um problema com apache, o problema é com "php built-in server", e o problema ocorre em php32bt e php64ibt, a situação é outra.

Comment: @stderr acabei de testar agora, o problema ocorre sem o router também, então não tem o que resolver no router

Answer (score 3):

Essa parece ser uma falha antiga do PHP, como pode ser visto [**aqui**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60471).

É somente uma mensagem de aviso, não é algo que irá comprometer a integridade da aplicação.

### Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

A mensagem `Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)` indica que uma requisição foi realizada mas nenhum dado foi recebido, como pode ser visto no código-fonte, isso é tratado na função [`php_cli_server_recv_event_read_request`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L2326):

```
static int php_cli_server_recv_event_read_request(php_cli_server *server, 
                                                  php_cli_server_client *client)
{
    char *errstr = NULL;
    int status = php_cli_server_client_read_request(client, &errstr);

    if (status < 0) {
        php_cli_server_logf("%s Invalid request (%s)", client->addr_str, errstr);
        efree(errstr);
        php_cli_server_close_connection(server, client);
        return FAILURE;
    } 

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

A mensagem é lançada quando o resultado da função [`php_cli_server_client_read_request`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1679) é negativo, observe abaixo onde isso acontece:

```
static int php_cli_server_client_read_request(php_cli_server_client *client, char **errstr)
{
    int nbytes_read;
    // ....
    nbytes_read = recv(client->sock, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);

    if (nbytes_read < 0) {
        int err = php_socket_errno();
        if (err == SOCK_EAGAIN) {
            return 0;
        }

        *errstr = php_socket_strerror(err, NULL, 0);
        return -1;

    } else if (nbytes_read == 0) { // Entra nessa condição
        *errstr = estrdup("Unexpected EOF");
        return -1;
    }   
    // ...
}
```

### Patch

[**Aqui**](https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=60471&patch=removes-unexpected-eof-message-from-cli-server.patch&revision=latest) tem uma proposta (remendo) para remover a mensagem.

### Causador

O que pode estar originando essas requisições, talvez seja, por você usar o Chrome, o serviço de previsão para carregar as páginas mais rapidamente, se você desativar essa opção, provavelmente a mensagem não vai aparecer novamente.

Para desativar, faça o seguinte:

- Clique em [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] ➝ **Configurações**.
- Na parte inferior, clique em **Mostrar configurações avançadas**.
- Na seção **Privacidade**, desmarque a caixa ao lado de **Usar um serviço de previsão para carregar páginas mais rapidamente**.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma alternativa é usar o modo de navegação anônima, o atalho é <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

<sup>**Nota**: Isso pode acontecer também em outros navegadores que tenham algum tipo de otimização semelhante ao do Chrome.</sup>

Comment: Com certeza mereceu a recompensa ;)